# Induction When There Is No Equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

This sounds confusing, but I will try to make it easy. The question is to prove the proposition

$P(n): 3^n – 1$ is divisible by $2$.

So I first used $k=1$, and saw that it works out to be true.

Then when I started to work on part 2, I got lost quickly. So I stated that we assume true for $P(k)$ which means $3^k - 1$ is divisible by 2.$

I then used $P(K)$ to try and prove, $3^{k+1} -1 = 3 \cdot 3^k -1$ is divisible by 2.

I am not sure what to do after this step since I'm accustom to proving propositions in the form of equations, and here, there is not another side of any equation.

Does the proof just end there?

Comment: 3^(k+1)=3*3^k not 2*3^k

Comment: Sorry about that, that's what I had on paper.

Comment: What you need to show is $3^{k+1}-1$ is divisible by $2$. To do that, write $$ 3^{k+1}-1-2+2 = 3(3^{k}-1)+2 $$ then use the induction hypothesis.

Comment: 3^n – 1, whatever you want to call it...

Comment: Ignore fleablood; If you're more comfortable with working with equations, you can state $3^n - 1 = 2k$ for some $k\in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: @fleablood  Again, you seem to put all your energy into trying to attack/confuse askers. Why?  If you have something constructive to say, wonderful.  But if you seek to shame, or harass OP's (e.g. in this case); go away.

Comment: I'm trying to help him/her out.  The issue seems to be confusing the proposition "$3^n -1$ is divisible by 2" with the equal sign in "$3^{k+1}-1 = 3*3^k-1$" and how to continue when the op gets confused how to continue with the equal sign  The thing is, the equal sign isn't defining the proposition. And that's where the confusion is.  In this case the equal sign is just a statement along the way to a bigger statement.  Doug M's answer demonstrates that quite well.

Comment: @fleablood If you sincerely want to help askers, then you need to address askers  or to clarify a misunderstanding more respectfully, and be less judgmental.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

proposition: $2$ divides $3^n - 1$

Proof by induction.

Base case: $n=1, 2$ divides $4$

Inductive hypothesis: 
Suppose for some $n, 2$ divides $3^n - 1$

We will show that: $2$ divides $3^{n+1} - 1$ when $2$ divides $3^n - 1$

$3^{n+1} - 1 = 3(3^n-1)+2$

$2$ divides $(3^n-1)$ from the inductive hypothesis, and $2$ divides $2$

QED